# Select as in SQL while selecting from Temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below code in which I am first creating a temp table and the second is part of a dynamic query I have in which I am creating a header row for my table by querying `tempdb.sys.Columns`.

The issue I have is that I am not sure how to alias the table columns so if the column is say ItemDesc, then I want the header to say "Item Description".

```
 create table #FeesCalculation
    (
        ItemId char(20), 
        ItemDesc varchar(max),  
        Units varchar(600) ,  
        Rate decimal(18,3), 
        Frequency varchar(60),
        Annual decimal(18,3),
        BasedOn nvarchar(max)  
    )    
    SELECT    
     @FIELDS=COALESCE(@FIELDS, '' '','''')+ ''<td style='' + ''"border:1px solid   black;color:white">'' +  name  +  ''</td>'' 
 FROM tempdb.sys.Columns
    WHERE object_id=object_id(''tempdb..#FeesCalculation'')
    AND name not like ''CustColHTML_ID'' 
    AND name not like ''ItemID''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT @FIELDS = (COALESCE(@FIELDS, '' '','''') + ''<td style='' + 
                  ''"border:1px solid   black;color:white">'' +
                  (CASE WHEN name = 'ItemDesc' THEN '[Item Description]' ELSE name END) +  ''</td>'' 
                 )
```

Comment: This is perfect..can u tell me how to handle multiple case scenarios

Comment: @user1221989 . . . Just add multiple `WHEN`/`THEN` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT REPLACE( @FIELDS, 'ItemDesc', 'Item Description' )